# gosimple/oauth2 and Google OAuth2

Tags: oauth, go

I'm using the [gosimple/oauth2](https://bitbucket.org/gosimple/oauth2/) package to handle OAuth2 logins for users. I have zero problems with the [GitHub example code](https://bitbucket.org/gosimple/oauth2/src/9f4d5eeac307/examples/github/github.go?at=default), which works perfectly and returns what I want.

I do, however, have issues getting it to work with Google. I've defined my scope correctly (as far as I can see), and I'm getting a token response, but once I enter it in, the application panics at ~line 68.

```
package main

import (
    "bitbucket.org/gosimple/oauth2"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var (
    // Register new app at https://github.com/settings/applications and provide
    // clientId (-id), clientSecret (-secret) and redirectURL (-redirect)
    // as imput arguments.
    clientId     = flag.String("id", "", "Client ID")
    clientSecret = flag.String("secret", "", "Client Secret")
    redirectURL  = flag.String("redirect", "http://httpbin.org/get", "Redirect URL")
    scopeURL     = flag.String("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "Scope URL")

    authURL    = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
    tokenURL   = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
    apiBaseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/"
)

const startInfo = `
Register new app at https://github.com/settings/applications and provide
-id, -secret and -redirect as input arguments.
`

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *clientId == "" || *clientSecret == "" {
        fmt.Println(startInfo)
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    // Initialize service.
    service := oauth2.Service(
        *clientId, *clientSecret, authURL, tokenURL)
    service.RedirectURL = *redirectURL
    service.Scope = *scopeURL

    // Get authorization url.
    aUrl := service.GetAuthorizeURL("")
    fmt.Println("\n", aUrl)

    // Open authorization url in default system browser.
    //webbrowser.Open(url)

    fmt.Printf("\nVisit URL and provide code: ")
    code := ""
    // Read access code from cmd.
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &code)
    // Get access token.
    token, _ := service.GetAccessToken(code)
    fmt.Println()

    // Prepare resource request.
    google := oauth2.Request(apiBaseURL, token.AccessToken)
    google.AccessTokenInHeader = false
    google.AccessTokenInHeaderScheme = "token"
    //google.AccessTokenInURL = true

    // Make the request.
    apiEndPoint := "user"
    googleUserData, err := google.Get(apiEndPoint)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Get:", err)
    }
    defer googleUserData.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("User info response:")
    // Write the response to standard output.
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, googleUserData.Body)

    fmt.Println()
}
```

And the panic:

`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x2341]`

This is the offending line:

`google := oauth2.Request(apiBaseURL, token.AccessToken)`

I'd appreciate help to get this working. Note that the code is just modified example code from the `gosimple/oauth2` repo I'm trying to debug this stage before wrapping it with the controller methods in my application.

Full stack trace as below:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x2341]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/matt/Desktop/tests/google_demo.go:68 +0x341

goroutine 2 [syscall]:

goroutine 5 [runnable]:
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc2000bd100)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1/src/pkg/net/http/transport.go:761 +0x64b
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1/src/pkg/net/http/transport.go:511 +0x574

goroutine 6 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc2000bd100)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1/src/pkg/net/http/transport.go:774 +0x26f
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1/src/pkg/net/http/transport.go:512 +0x58b
```

... and forcing a panic on a token error:

`panic: No access token found, response: [78 111 116 32 70 111 117 110 100]`

Comment: Some object in the code must be nil.  Could you tell us the exact line where the panic happens and  post a copy of that line so we can find it in the code?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Line 68 (it's in the post, just buried; forgot SO doesn't have line numbers)

Comment: You wrote a tilde before it, so I thought it might be an approximate line number.  So based on your edit I would guess that `token` is nil.  I wonder why.

Comment: Actually you should give the whole stack trace so we can see whether  the panic happened inside the oauth library or your code.

Comment: What is the second return value from `service.GetAccessToken(code)`?  You are ignoring it by assigning it to `_`.  If it is an error, you should definitely assign it to `err` and check if it is nil.  Use this code: `if err != nil { log.Fatal(err); }`  That will probably tell you why the code is failing.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Have added the full trace, which seems to indicate the problem is created when the program calls net/http. I've also caught the error (noting that this is demo code; not mine!) and it's definitely a token issue. My feeling is that Google's tokens, which start with [1-9] and a forward-slash, are breaking the parser in the library.

Comment: OK, then we have been looking in the wrong place.  You should figure out why GetAccessToken is returning that error.  You might need to add a bunch of fmt.Println statements to the library, or somehow use a debugger.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks, I appreciate the help. I've just done a run with the other OAuth2 library (https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/) and it worked as expected, so it's definitely a library bug.

Comment: @elithrar - It looks like you've found the answer ("it's defintely a library bug"). Could you add that as an answer below and accept it, so it's easier for others to see when they find this page? (Your comment was hidden when I first viewed the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug in the library's token handling, which I logged with the author and which was fixed within the day: https://bitbucket.org/gosimple/oauth2/commits/e8e925ffb2424645cceaa9534e0ed9a28e564a20